# Format Datatype for Time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, time

```
result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE event_type = 'ALARM_OPENED' AND severity = '2'")
equipments = result.map { |print_this| [print_this['sourcetime'], print_this['description']] }
p equipments
```

The Datatype for `sourcetime` in MySQL workbench is set to TIME

The result I get is `2000-01-01 12:00:04 +0100`

I would like to get only the time `12:00:04` and drop the date and +0100

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve: How to format the output (hint: `strftime`)? Or how to change the timezone to UTC?

Comment: @spickermann Yes, I would like to format the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps are necessary to achieve this:

1. [`Time.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) the string returned from your database into an instance of `Time`.
2. Use [`Time#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to format the instance of `Time` into the desired output format.

To just display the hours, minutes and seconds of a time (without the date and timezone information) use the `'%H:%M:%S'` directive (see the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more examples).

```
require 'time' # `Time.parse` is not Ruby Core but from the Standard Library

equipments = result.map do |record| 
  [
    Time.parse(record['sourcetime']).strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
    record['description']
  ]
end
```

Comment: Nice! May I add for future users that the .to_s is needed to prevent  error `Time.parse(record['sourcetime'].to_s).strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: What kind of error do you get without the `to_s`? The `pg` returns date and time column in a string representation, there shouldn't be a need to call `to_s` on something that is already a string.

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Time into String`

Comment: Wow, that is unexpected. It seems to depend on the setup or the gem version if a string or a time is returned. Just skip the `Time.parse` part your case, `record['sourcetime'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')` should work in your context.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try **strftime("%I:%M%p")**

```
equipments = result.map { |print_this| print_this.sourcetime.strftime("%I:%M%p") }
```

Comment: 'sourcetime' is my column name. Is there another way to add .strftime("%I:%M%p")

Comment: if you saved in string date, just convert into date eg:) sourcetime.to_date.strftime("%I:%M%p")

Comment: I've edited to show my full code. My 'sourcetime' is in a nested array. I don't see how I could put it into a string to convert it.